# PHP Querying Session_ID Inside a Database

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

I've been attempting to find the session id on my site so I can use it to query my MySQL database but I keep getting the error 'Undefined variable: _SESSION in...'

Here's my code:

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE _id = " . $_SESSION['_id_of_user'])))
```

And here is where I defined my session id:

```
$qry = "Select name, email, username, _id from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";

$result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
{
    $this->HandleError("Error logging in. The username or password does not match");
    return false;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$_SESSION['name_of_user']     = $row['name'];
$_SESSION['email_of_user']    = $row['email'];
$_SESSION['username_of_user'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['_id_of_user']      = $row['_id'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start the session before your sql query:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

```
session_start();
```

Then you should get the current session id with this:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

```
$current_session_id = session_id();
```

Comment: And if you want to use a database to store your sessions, then read the examples/classes given here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Answer (score 1):

Do you do a `session_start()` before trying to write to it?
Also try putting

```
var_dump("<PRE>", $_SESSION);
```

before you attemptd to read from it to see whats actually in there.
So you would have:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name_of_user']     = $row['name'];
$_SESSION['email_of_user']    = $row['email'];
$_SESSION['username_of_user'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['_id_of_user']      = $row['_id'];
```

and:

```
var_dump("<PRE>", $_SESSION);
$qry = "Select name, email, username, _id from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";
```

Also I am wondering if you can do this with $this->tablename :

```
$qry = "Select name, email, username, _id from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";
```

Try:

```
 $qry = "Select name, email, username, _id from ".$this->tablename." where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";
```